# Is it possible to generate jmeter html report using properties file as parameter using command line query

Tags: jmeter

below is the command i used

jmeter.bat -n -t C:\Users\vingale\Desktop\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.0\Writeback\Iconductor_Writeback_With_Configurationbck_Property.jmx -l "C:\Users\vingale\Desktop\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.0\Writeback\output\result2.csv" -e -o "C:\Users\vingale\Desktop\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.0\Writeback\output\html" -p QA.properties

if i remove the properties file parameter then the html report get generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter uses reportgenerator.properties file for HTML report related configuration.

Official documentation recommends not to change the content in reportgenerator.properties file. It suggest user to copy the properties to be changed into user.property file and provide required values.

Following could be used to generate HTML report at the end of the testing

```
jmeter.bat -n -t C:\Users\vingale\Desktop\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.0\Writeback\Iconductor_Writeback_With_Configurationbck_Property.jmx -l "C:\Users\vingale\Desktop\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.0\Writeback\output\result2.csv" -e -o "C:\Users\vingale\Desktop\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.0\Writeback\output\html" -q user.properties
```

You will have to ensure the report output directory is empty.You will have to manually clear-out the directory or ask JMeter to delete the content forcefully with ***-f*** option

> -f, --forceDeleteResultFile
> force delete existing results files and web report folder if
> present before starting the test

Answer (score 1):

You're using `-p` command line argument which acts as the replacement for **jmeter.properties** file which contains [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) which is necessary for proper dashboard generation.

If you have an **extra** file with properties used in your test you should use [`-q` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) instead of `-p`

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Going forward get used to look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), in the majority of cases it should contain sufficient information in order to guess the root cause of the issue